# Rational cohomology ring of complex Grassmannian.

Tags: reference-request, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry

The rational cohomology ring of complex projective space $\mathbb{CP}^{m}$ is $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[X]}{(X^{m+1})}.$ This is given in the book of Allen Hatcher. I want to understand the rational cohomology ring of complex Grassmannian. The simplest case after complex projective spaces is $Gr(m,2).$ What is the rational cohomology ring of $Gr(m,2)?$ Moreover what is the Betti numbers of $Gr(m,2).$ If some one know good reference about general case please share with me. In the paper ''ENDOMORPHISMS OF THE COHOMOLOGY
OF COMPLEX GRASSMANNIANS'' MICHAEL HOFFMAN cite a paper of A. Borel in which the presentation is given but this paper is not in English.

Comment: I think that Bott and Tu may compute this, but I don't have my copy to check now. Perhaps it is also in McCleary's book, since he explains how to compute cohomology rings of homogeneous spaces, but again I don't have the copy with me to check.

Comment: There is a nice section on complex Grassmannian in the book of Bott and Tu. Proposition 23.1 gives the Poincare Polynomial of complex Grassmannian. It is very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a presentation of the (integral) cohomology ring given in Section 5.8 (in the published version) of the book *3264 And All That* by Eisenbud and Harris. (They talk in terms of the Chow ring, but in this case the two things are the same.)